# How to programmatically specify the file name for RollingFileAppender in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

*Background:*

My application allows two operating modes that can be chosen from a GUI.
If it operates as a server, I want to direct the logs into the `server.log` file.
If it operates as a client, I want to direct the logs into the `client.log` file.

*Question:*

> How to programmingly specify different names for different modes for RollingFileAppender in log4j?

**Added (10-29-2014):** The current answer by @Manish Maheshwari does not work for me. It raises the warning `log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [file]` and it does not write logs into file.

---

*My attempt:*

I define `RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender` class which extends `RollingFileAppender` and overrides the `setFile()` method.

```
public class RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {
    @Override
    public void  setFile(String fileName) {
        super.setFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

My `RollingFileAppender` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//LOGGER" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration>
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=[[What to do here? org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]]
    log4j.appender.file.File = [[I don't know how to do here.]]
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=50MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
</log4j:configuration>
```

However I don't know what to do in Java code and the `log4j.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified classname for `RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender` in `log4j.appender.file` property.
Try removing the File line from config.

Use this at bootstrap:

```
RollingFileAppender app = new RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender();
app.setFile(myfile);
BasicConfigurator.configure(app);
```

Comment: For the qualified classname, Eclipse context menu of "copy qualified name" gives me `/PHAULR-master/util/log4j/RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender.java`. `/PHAULR-master` is the project. Then I used `util.log4j.RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender` in `log4j.appender.file` and got an error `log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [null]`.

Comment: Fully qualified name would mean the name of the class along with the package name, that you would have declared when writing the class. By your error message, seems that your RoleSpecificRollingFileAppender is not picked up. Correct the FQ class name.

Comment: The error involving qualified classname has been solved. A warning `log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [file]` arises. And it does not write logs into file.